# How to execute script once in Python

Tags: python, monitoring

I have following Python code and i want to execute ServiceRestart only once.

Current situation is i have configured four errors which my following script will get from JSON file and send email alerts but as i have added service restart under the **else** it will restart the service 4 times if those 4 errors found at a same time.

I want to run serviceRestart only once.

```
        # Logic to read the result file and send email
    if self.flag:
        fn = open(result_file_name, 'r+')
        result_data = fn.read()
        self.logger.info('Calling send email method')
        self.logger.info(result_data)
        if(((day == 'Saturday') and (hr >= '06' and hr <'12')) or (day == 
        'Sunday')):
            print('Mail will not go')
        else:                
            self.email_util.send_email(result_data)
            serviceName = "raha-connector"
            win32serviceutil.RestartService(serviceName) //this i want to execute once
            result_data = 'Connector started successfully'
            self.email_util.send_email(result_data)
            self.logger.info('Match found, hence send email method called')
            self.logger.info('End of search_file method : file_name -%s, 
            criteria - %s, last scanned row - %s',
            file_name, criteria, last_scanned_row)
```

I have tried using counter but its not working. I tried even with loop it didn't worked as well.

Please provide some methods to execute serviceRestart only once irrespective of error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean for that.

```
has_restarted = False
 # Logic to read the result file and send email
    if self.flag:
        fn = open(result_file_name, 'r+')
        result_data = fn.read()
        self.logger.info('Calling send email method')
        self.logger.info(result_data)
        if(((day == 'Saturday') and (hr >= '06' and hr <'12')) or (day == 
        'Sunday')):
            print('Mail will not go')
        else:                
            self.email_util.send_email(result_data)
            serviceName = "raha-connector"
            if not has_restarted:
                win32serviceutil.RestartService(serviceName) //this i want to execute once
                has_restarted = True
            result_data = 'Connector started successfully'
            self.email_util.send_email(result_data)
            self.logger.info('Match found, hence send email method called')
            self.logger.info('End of search_file method : file_name -%s, 
            criteria - %s, last scanned row - %s',
            file_name, criteria, last_scanned_row)
```

You have a boolean `has_restarted` which is `False` at start. Once you use the restart function in the if statement I've added, `has_restarted` becomes `True` so it will never pass the if statement and restart will not be issued.